# How i will implement Passwordless authentication in wso2is version 5.8

Tags: authentication, wso2-identity-server

Currently, we have wso2is v5.8 in our product to authenticate the end-user (end-user is store in our user store (AD/LDAP), so my question is I need to implement passwordless authentication
in our product so how, I will achieve that, if some can give an idea, it would be great

Answer (score 0):

You can use `FIDO2` (Fast IDentity Online) for passwordless authentication in `WSO2IS-5.10.0` for the version `WSO2IS-5.8.0` you can use device registration with `FIDO` and `FIDO` authenticator.

1. Go to the dashboard URL: https://localhost:9443/dashboard/
2. Enter your username and password and click the Sign In button.
3. Navigate to the ***My Profile*** section by clicking the associated ***View Details*** button.
4. Click Manage ***U2F Authentication***.
5. You can add a new U2F device to your account and remove it when needed. The new U2F device can be added by clicking the ***Attach FIDO Token*** button. Then you need to touch the '**key**' icon on the FIDO device in order to complete the adding process.

[image: attached FIDO deivce]

6. Go to https://localhost:9443/carbon/admin/login.jsp and log in to ***management console***
7. Create a Service Provider. (How to configure service provider, click [here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS530/Adding+and+Configuring+a+Service+Provider))
8. Access the service provider you just created and expand ***Local & Outbound Authentication Configuration*** and select ***Local Authentication*** and `fido`

[image: FIDO authenticator selection]

9. Click update.

For more information go through the below links,

1. https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/learn/passwordless-authentication-using-fido2/
2. https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/develop/fido-rest-api/
3. https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/learn/multi-factor-authentication-using-fido/

   (If you are trying MFA with FIDO you need to add `basic authenticator`  first which is username and password one)